# Updating form in Django. How to design?

Tags: django

I'm a django newbie.

I have this model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

How to create view to update quantity of my all Item?

views:

```
def item_list(request):
    item = Product.objects.all()[:6]
    return render_to_response('item.html',{'item':item},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

form:

```
from django import forms

class QuantityForm(forms.Form):
    quan = forms.IntegerField()
```

template:

```
{% for i in item %}
    {{ i.name }}
    {{ i.quantity }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to do something like this(after clicking "update" value `quantity` in my model should be actualize):

[image]

Please any help. Thanks

Comment: look into `formsets`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: This is the only way out? I need a simple solution

Comment: formsets are simple. Or, you can create forms for each, and do an ajax submit

Comment: U want to change quantity of all 6 objects?clarify!

Comment: No. I want change quantity of one objects. This is something like shopping cart. For example: Item 4 Quantity: I entered 8 and click update. New value is saved in database.

Comment: I edited my answer! take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a view, which retrieves item id and quantity value, updates relative `Item` instance and redirects you back to the page. Here is an example:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404

@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def update_item(request)
    id = request.POST.get('id', None) #retrieve id
    quantity = request.POST.get('q', None)  #retrieve quantity
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=id) #if no item found raise page not found
    if quantity:
        #updating item quantity
        item.quantity = quantity
        item.save()

    return redirect('my-item-list-view-name')
```

Also you need to create urlpattern for the view in your `urls.py`. For example:

```
...
url(r'^update-item/$', 'update_item', name='update_item'),
...
```

Then you can make a forms for each item on a template:

```
{% for i in item %}
    <form action="{% url 'update_item' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ i.name }}
        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ i.id }}" />
        <input name="q" type="text" value="{{ i.quantity }}" />
        <input type="submit" value="update" />
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to offer a solution as simple as possible. You should know that django provides a lot of cool stuff, that can help your to solve your problem much efficiently, such as forms, modelforms, formsets...

Answer (score 2):

in `views.py` :

```
   if request.method=='POST':
      if 'txt1' in request.POST:
         if request.POST['txt1']!='':
            obj=Item.objects.get(pk=request.POST['item1'])
            obj.quantity=request.POST['txt1']
            obj.save()
      if 'txt2' in request.POST:
         if request.POST['txt2']!='':
            obj=Item.objects.get(pk=request.POST['item2'])
            obj.quantity=request.POST['txt2']
            obj.save()
      if 'txt3' in request.POST:
         if request.POST['txt3']!='':
            obj=Item.objects.get(pk=request.POST['item3'])
            obj.quantity=request.POST['txt3']
            obj.save()
      #continue this code for all 6 items
```

**update:**

of course U can put this in a loop:

```
for i in range(1,6):
   if 'txt'+str(i) in request.POST:
      if request.POST['txt'+str(i)]!='':
         obj=Item.objects.get(pk=request.POST['item'+str(i)]
         obj.quantity=request.POST['txt'+str(i)]
         obj.save()
```

in `template`:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
{% for i in item %}

      {{ i.name }}:<input type='text' id='txt{{forloop.counter}}' value='{{ i.quantity }}' /><input type='hidden' id='item{{forloop.counter}}' value='{{item.pk}}' /><input type='submit' value='increase' id='sbm{{forloop.counter}}' />

{% endfor %}
</form>
```

**update:** `forloop.counter` is the current for counter,1,2,3...

Answer (score 2):

You can either create a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) for your `item` and then use [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) or if you can use jquery to submit a ajax request to a django view that updates the item for the selected model

```
$('<yourbuttonclass').onClick(function(e){
    e.preventdefault()
    $.post(urlToPost, dataFromTextField&csrfmiddlewaretken={{csrf_token}})
     .success('Successfully Updated')
     ....

In your view:

#Get the item id from urlconf
@ajax_request
def update_view(request, item_id)
   #Update your item
   return {'Success': 'Updated to blah'}
```

I like to use the `ajax_request` decorator from [here](https://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying) for sending ajax response. You can also send a `HTTPResponse('Successfully updated')`

If you want to creating a Restful resource would be a great way too and then you get an interface to create, update, read and delete from a single pattern. Read up on [Django Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. How to exactly do this using a formset? I learn django. 
I need an example

Comment: Did you get the concept of a ModelForm? If yes, then just do ItemFormSet = formset_factory(ItemForm, extra=6) in your python django shell and print for form in ItemFormset: print(form.as_table()). That should help ypu understand. I actually do not like the fact that beyond a certain point customizing forms in django using custom widgets makes it messy and prefer using jquery for the same. You don't really lose much.